# How can I list all Task- or Task<T>-returning method invokings that lack an await call in a solution?

Tags: c#, async-await

How can I list all `Task`- or `Task<T>`-returning method invokings that lack an `await` call in a solution?

I tried searching for a few things on Google, but nothing popped up.

For example:

```
public Task<bool> DoWork()
{
    return Task.FromResult(true); // would be listed, even though it's "correct"
}

public async Task DoMoreWork()
{
    await DoWork(); // would not be listed
    DoWork(); // would be listed
    DoWork(); // would be listed a second time in this same method
}

public void DoEvenMoreWork()
{
    DoWork(); // would be listed
}
```

We're using .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: This is going to be provably impossible.  Consider cases such as where you create a task, put it in a list, then await all of the items in that list.  Now consider cases where that list is mutated during that time (or simply passed to another method that could mutate it).  The false positive rate of something like this is going to be *enormous*, to the point of rendering it useless.  If you try and actually use a tool like this regularly the members of your team will end up writing far worse (or even non-functional) TPL code just to try to appease this horrific code analysis rule.

Comment: The compiler already helps you when your method is declared with `async` by providing the following warning if you forget the `await`: `warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.`  Isn't that good enough?

Comment: @sstan While that one is helpful, I guess I'm more concerned about the last one - when the method is not declared as `async`.

Comment: @Servy So you mean like `foreach (var a in awaits) { a(); }` where `awaits` is a `List<Func<Task>>`?  Assuming `Func`'s are methods, then there would be one missing `await`.  I think it's pretty deterministic - look for all method call expressions that are known to have `Task` as a base class for its result type that are contained within a non-async method/delegate (since as sstan pointed out C# already gives a warning for async methods).  I just thought this may have already been solved.  I don't see how this is provably impossible.  I'm just looking for static analysis.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared No, that's not what I said at all.  I said a list of tasks, not a list of delegates that create tasks.  If you write `var tasks = new[]{FooAsync(), BarAsync()}; foreach(var task in tasks) await task;` trying to analize that program to determine that the tasks returned by `FooAsync()` and `BarAsync()` is not going to be possible in the general case, and even lots of very common practices would be extremely hard, if even possible, to write an analyzer for that wouldn't have errors.

Comment: @Servy I think see what you're saying.  I guess I meant analysis that wasn't "intelligent" at all - meaning in that case it would list two errors because `FooAsync()` and `BarAsync()` were missing immediate `await` calls.  Sure, they're ultimately `await`-ed in your example, but I described would be useful (for my purposes, anyway).  It wouldn't be enforced as a rule - I just want to do a sweep through our codebase to see what methods on classes we've made that aren't `await`-ed.  Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared And my point was that as a result of that, you're going to have an extremely high false positive rate, making this analysis extremely unproductive at best, or actively harmful at worst.  Quite simply when actually using the TPL to write code it's pretty rare to follow the exact pattern you're describing.  It's extremely common to not await every single task the moment its created.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared: 1) Download Roslyn. 2) Hack until it works.

Comment: Not a perfect answer and it requires ReSharper, but the best thing I've found for this is the fact that ReSharper will tell you if you have a method where the return value is not being used (in this case, awaited). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276479/find-awaitable-methods-in-code-with-visual-studio