# Find awaitable methods in code with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, async-await

I have a problem where `async` methods are being called in the code without `await` in front of it. Is there a way to find all the awaitable methods that do not have `await`?

**Edit** - I'm particularly concerned with the scenario where multiple async methods are being called (ignoring the return values), but only one has `await` which is enough to make Visual Studio not warn about it.

Comment: Not that an answer was found, but a very similar question was asked here: [How can I list all Task- or Task<T>-returning method invokings that lack an await call in a solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986605/how-can-i-list-all-task-or-taskt-returning-method-invokings-that-lack-an-awai)

Comment: You could try doing a search for `public Task<`.

Comment: It's impossible, in the general case, to determine if you have any tasks that you aren't awaiting.  You can always find some way of tricking your analysis tool into thinking that a given task isn't being awaited even though it is.

Comment: Not trying to be that guy, but an async method doesn't have to be awaited--it just allows await to be used inside it. Can you clarify as to whether you are talking about async methods with no awaits inside them, methods that return Tasks that should be awaited, or were you under the impression every method marked async should be awaited?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ReSharper and turn solution-wide analysis on, your methods that are returning tasks that are not being awaited will have the Task portion of the method signature grayed out due to "return value is not used." The caveat here is that this will only find methods that are not being awaited anywhere in your solution; the warning will go away after one or more usages are updated to await (or use/reference the `Task`).

If you're looking for async methods that don't contain an await call (meaning they don't need to be labeled async), ReSharper will tell you about that too in a similar fashion.

```
    class AClass
    {
        public async void Foo() //async grayed out
        {
            DoSomethingAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        public Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync() //Task<bool> grayed out
        {
            return Task.Run(() => true);
        }    
    }
```

Note this will not work if you have code that looks like this:

```
    class AClass
    {
        public async void Foo()
        {
            bool b = DoSomethingAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        public Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            return Task.Run(() => true);
        }    
    }
```

The `async` keyword, if present, will still be flagged, which means you can probably figure out pretty quickly a Task is not being awaited, but if the calling method is not marked async you are out of luck.

Comment: I updated my question. I was concerned with multiple async methods being called but only one using an `await`, but you now bring up another concern of when the calling method lacks the `async` and there are no `await` In either case, it sounds like this is not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: At least in the second case I could write a regex that looks for method calls followed by a ".Result" to get most, if not all, of those types of calls.

Comment: Yeah, in order to accomplish what you're asking you would have to rely on code analysis to find all methods that return tasks and track how the result of each invocation is being used. That would be preferable to treating the scenario you describe as a warning, since it's fairly common to have cases where you want to await a method in one place and call it synchronously in another. For example, if you wanted to await a method in main you'd have trouble--you can't mark main async.